# Is there a way to move the memory offset of the Global Offset Table using GCC or by manually linking?

Tags: security, buffer-overflow, exploit

I want to move the offset in memory of the Global Offset Table in my program to harden against ret2dlresolve, as I'm working on a CTF challenge.

I've been looking into writing linker scripts, but I can't really seem to figure out, how to both move it using a linker script and include libc at the same time.

Is there any native way to do this in GCC?

It's also important that the GOT is moved independently from the base of the program (where the executable part is), as hardening against ret2dlresolve only works if the GOT is at least x amount of bytes away from the PLT.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! :-)